# Importance of crossover frequency

Tags: audio, speakers

Speaker manufacturers often state crossover frequencies in the specs. What is the importance of this value?

Let's take for example two equivalent active powered 2-way boxes with crossover frequencies set to 900Hz and 800Hz. What would be the difference? I remember having read that lower crossover levels allow the woofer to reproduce better lower frequencies and/or extend its low end frequency response.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the speakers inside. If the bass driver happens to be crappy at reproducing 800 Hz and above then it will be paired with a "tweater" that is capable of covering the 800 Hz area and the crossover will be designed accordingly so that power is directed only/mainly to the speaker that is best suited. There is no mystery.

Comment: *tweeter - "tweater" is either NSFW or crass.

Comment: Spelling isn't mi strong poynt.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Andy's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/244525/53375), there's also an acoustic component to it.  Regardless of the specific crossover frequency, that's the most likely place for a speaker assembly to be awkward, even multi-amped ones with all digital processing.

To be anything other than a point source that radiates in a circular cone pattern, the radiating device (speaker, explosion, highway, etc.) has to be physically bigger than 1/2 wavelength.  Obviously, that's much easier to do with single tweeters than for single woofers.  (Note 1)

So the speakers' advertised coverage is mostly for the tweeter, and for "acceptable" performance at the crossover frequency where you're listening to the sum of both drivers.  A difference of 1/2 wavelength away from the listener means that the drivers cancel instead of add.  You really don't want that happening in the intelligible region of speech if you can avoid it.

What happens when you move off-axis in the smaller direction (usually vertical for mains with the traditional over/under arrangement, or horizontal for stage wedges that end up side-by-side) depends on the speaker:

- If you get outside tweeter's radiation pattern before you get a 1/2 wavelength difference in distance to each one, you'll simply lose the tweeter and the woofer would still sound okay.  You'll still have the "boom" and "rumble", but the "crispness", "sizzle", "air", etc. would be missing.
- If you get a difference of 1/2 wavelength while still inside the tweeter's radiation pattern, you'll get a notch at that frequency.  For a really steep crossover (probably digital), you might not notice, but a shallow one (probably passive analog) will make a "hole" that can be anything from mildly interesting to super annoying if it happens to be smack in the middle of the intelligible region of speech.  No amount of digital smarts can fix that without creating the same problem at a different listening position.

Both effects actually start happening as soon as you move away from 0 degrees on-axis, but the manufacturer's specified radiation pattern is the farthest off-axis you can get where they've designed it to still sound acceptable by their own standards.

---

Note 1: The line array is an attempt at a large radiating device that is easy to set up, so that its radiation pattern can be better tuned for where the audience actually is.  From a physical perspective, it doesn't have to a a vertical line that hits a horizontal audience, but most of them are made to solve that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a larger diameter speaker can reproduce low frequencies better, but the larger cone is less effective at higher frequencies. To get a wide frequency response you could just wire a large diameter 'bass' speaker in parallel with progressively smaller 'mid-range' and 'tweeter' speakers, but each speaker will still draw power from the amp and make *some* sound (possibly distorted) even outside its useful frequency range.

Also the power required to reproduce music reduces at higher frequencies, so the tweeter can be made smaller with a lower power rating *provided* that it only gets the high frequencies and doesn't have to handle the greater power at lower frequencies.

In a speaker that has multiple 'drivers' (individual speakers) in the box to handle different frequencies, the crossover filter network routes the signal to the speaker that that can make best use of the power in each frequency band. The frequencies allocated to each range depend on the particular drivers used. so if (for example) the mid-range driver should take over from the bass driver above 800Hz then the crossover would be set to that frequency.

In practice it's not quite that simple. The crossover filter response is quite broad and each driver has its own unique level response and impedance variation with frequency, so the optimum crossover frequency may vary depending on interaction between the different drivers in the speaker system.